# Wanting to use a Progress Bar with SQLBulkCopy

Tags: vb.net, progress-bar, sqlbulkcopy

Question on an app I'm developing using VB.NET. I'm wanting to use a progress bar to show the progress of my `SqlBulkCopy` procedure. I've looked up some ways and was wondering if using an `AddHandler` in my `SqlBulkCopy` procedure, using `SqlRowsCopied` is a possible way to calculate the progress. And if so, how would I implement this, as I'm a bit new to progress bars in VB.NET. Let me know if there's a better way of going around this, all answers are very appreciated! THANKS! Just a small snippet of my `SqlBulkCopy` being executed.

(FYI: Not showing anything I've attempted with the progress bar)

Progress bar is named `toolStripProgressBar`:

```
Dim copy As New SqlBulkCopy(con)

For Each dc As DataColumn In dtDataCopy.Columns
    copy.ColumnMappings.Add(dc.ColumnName, dc.ColumnName)
Next

copy.DestinationTableName = TableName
copy.BulkCopyTimeout = 360 
copy.BatchSize = 1000
copy.WriteToServer(dtDataCopy)
copy.Close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the documentation states, the `SqlRowsCopied` event is dependent on the `NotifyAfter` property, NOT the `BatchSize` property.  You would set the `Maximum` of your `ProgressBar` to the total number of rows and the `Step` property to the same as the `NotifyAfter` value.  Each time the `SqlRowsCopied` event is raised, you call `PerformStep` on the `ProgressBar` and it will increment by the number of rows that have been copied.

Alternatively, you can simply assign the `e.RowsCopied` value to the `Value` property of the `ProgressBar`.  There is a code example provided in the MSDN documentation for the event.  It's to be hoped that you have consulted the documentation before posting this question.